# Azure DevOps Pipeline Release - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We've configured and run Azure DevOps Pipeline builds and releases for a year plus. We deploy to Azure App Services. Recently we began migrating some app services into an ASE (Azure Service Environment). This has required creating new Release definitions to deploy to the new ASE instances of our sites. The new Release pipelines failed with various errors or warnings that all contained **Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND**.

Examples:

> Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxxx.scm.xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net xxxx.scm.xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net:443

> 2020-06-10T15:18:33.6525723Z ##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxxx-staging.scm.xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net xxxx-staging.scm.xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net:443
>   2020-06-10T15:18:33.7227144Z ##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxxx.scm.xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net xxxx.scm.xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net:443

**getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND** looks to be a generic error associated with a lot of different issues. Would like to know if anyone has encounteed and found a fix for it in the context of Azure DevOps releases into ASE.

Comment: I had the same issue, but the given answer didn't work for me.  Our issue was down to the ILB ASE not having the required entries on internal DNS.  This can be resolved by creating those entries in DNS, or by faking them on the agent's hosts file (in our case, via the pipeline; though you could also put them on the agent image if preferred).  https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/14795/3083

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question here. Maybe this will save someone the several hours of work it took me to find the solution.

The answer in our case was simple: Select the **Default** agent pool in the Releases **Run on agent - Agent pool** field. It appears this gets set to another value when creating a new release. Once **Agent pool** was set to Default, the error went away.

[image: Releases task screenshot]

Comment: He kenswdev, it's great that you've found the answer and share the useful info here. You can consider accepting it as answer so that more members can benefit from the accepted answer. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [how to mark my own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), just a reminder :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It automatically selects the default agent even though you select the correct one in the build pipeline. This really saved me many hours.